# Data getting scraped in a single column instead of table format

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to parse data out of a table from a webpage. However, when i run it I get scraped data in a single column instead of a table format. What type of change should I make in my script to get data in a table format? Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/")

table_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]

for item in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td"):

    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

What I meant by table format is something like below. However I'm getting data in a single column instead of several columns like below.

[image]

Comment: don't you need specification of players on Forwards, Midfielders, Goalkeepers and Defenders? the way you're looping data won't give you this char.
Also selenium is too "heavy" in general, I'd use it only as last option. This particular page you are parsing is well structured, I'd recommend using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a table format'? Please specify that.

Comment: he wants the table as is presented.. but as you know when you scrape the ENTIRE table rowswith out then using an other loop with the ranges... I mean... Its the common thing to to scrape the cloums as the get all the ITEMS or VALUE together in each a respects list then use panda to slap it all together ... Or after each clomn has its values and the key ... the format print or the to prints all at the same rand and time... I mean also... no bs4?  you need a real parser

Comment: Ah ok..., justsaw your pic...you have to split the tables by column  so you create a list then can  ranges toiter over the ranges and format the print out... much more complicated to explain than do lol... Cant iterate hrough one big text split....]

Comment: WELL ACTUALLY!! you can split that ... b

Comment: come to think of it... dude, pandas... cut your code in half... also bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for item in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    print(item.text.split())
```

it will give you a list for each player separately.

Notice, that tag in .find_elements_by_xpath() is changed

Further,
you can make readable table like this:

```
...(your previous code)...
data=[]
for item in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    data.append(item.text.split())

format_table = '{:8s}' + 4 * '{:>10s}'
for lst in data:
    print(format_table.format(*lst))
```

Another version (to properly catch names with whitespaces like "de Goa"):

```
data=[]
temp=[]
for item in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    for i in item.find_elements_by_xpath('td'):
        temp.append(i.text)
    data.append(temp)
    temp=[]
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy Fialkovskiy, for your robust answer. It did what I expected. FYI, if it were not for selenium I know how to parse that table using bs4 or xpath. I got stuck because I never used selenium to scrape any table. That is because I chose that page. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy Fialkovskiy, one last thing you might wanna consider watching from this thread. Split function causes a little trouble here. If any player's name is separated by a space as in, "de Gea" then it creates a new column to display a single name separately whereas the column number for that table should always be four. You will be more clear when you follow the link. Any workaround in your mind for this! Thanks in advance. "https://www.dropbox.com/s/79frhafppxs32cn/player_list.csv?dl=0"

Comment: modified my answer, check if it suits, please